# For loop calculation incorrect

Tags: python, for-loop, operators, python-3.4

So for the following code that calculates mathematical expressions in Reverse Polish Notation (RPN), the final calculation (output) seems to be incorrect for certain inputs.

Example inputs:

- [10, 10, "add", 2 "divide"] is equivalent to (10+10)/2 and should produce an output of 10
- [3, 1, "multiply", 2 "divide"] is equivalent to (3*1)/2 and should produce an output of 1.5

(All outputs should be floats)

```
def evalSimpleEqn(eqn):
    result = []
    for x in eqn:
        if x == "add":
            result.append( result.pop() + result.pop() )
        elif x == "subtract":
            result.append( result.pop() - result.pop())
        elif x == "multiply":
            result.append( result.pop() * result.pop() )
        elif x == "divide":
             y = ((result.pop()))
             z = (result.pop())
             result.append( z/y )
        else:
              result.append(x)

    return (result[-1])
```

Specifically, when I input:
[12, 8, "subtract", 2, "divide", 4, "divide", 1, "add"]

The function returns 0.5 instead of 1.5. How do I fix this? Thank you for any help!

Comment: Please fix your indentation.  Changing the indentation changes the meaning of the code in Python.

Comment: Try debugging and see which of the operations gave the wrong result.

Comment: Subtraction uses the wrong order of arguments, so you'll get a negative result.

Comment: The thing is it works for other inputs but not this one?
@SvenMarnach, how would I fix this? I'm sure what you exactly mean.

Comment: I'd guess it has something to do with the order of the `pop()`ed operands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is in the subtract operation: the operands are interchanged in your implementation. you just have to treat it the same way you treat the division. for addition and multiplication the order does not matter.

```
def rpn_eval(s):
    result = []
    for x in s:
        print(result)
        if x == "add":
            result.append(result.pop() + result.pop())
        elif x == "subtract":
            y = result.pop()
            x = result.pop()
            result.append(x - y)
        elif x == "multiply":
            result.append(result.pop() * result.pop())
        elif x == "divide":
            y = result.pop()
            z = result.pop()
            result.append(z / y)
        else:
            result.append(x)

    return result[-1]
```

and it may not be a good idea to call your function `eval` that name is [taken](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#eval).

Comment: Yes, I just realised eval was taken; nice pick up. Thank you for your answer, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, another way to do it that is more easily extensible:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""Example code showing how to build an easily extensible RPN calculator"""

def rpn_eval(expression):
    """Calculates the passed expression list and returns the result"""
    result = []
    ops = {"add":float.__radd__,
           "subtract":float.__rsub__,
           "multiply":float.__rmul__,
           "divide":float.__rtruediv__
          }
    for arg in expression:
        result.append(arg if arg not in ops
                      else ops[arg](result.pop().__float__(), result.pop()))
    return result[-1]

def main():
    """main function"""
    tests = [
        [10, [10, 10, "add", 2, "divide"]],
        [1.5, [3, 1, "multiply", 2, "divide"]],
        [1.5, [12, 8, "subtract", 2, "divide", 4, "divide", 1, "add"]]
        ]

    for ans, expr in tests:
        calc_ans = rpn_eval(expr)
        print '{} == {}?  {}'.format(ans, calc_ans, ans == calc_ans)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

two changes in main code

```
def evalSimpleEqn(eqn):
    result = []
    for x in eqn:
        if x == "add":
            result.append( result.pop() + result.pop() )
        elif x == "subtract":
            # (1) reorder operands, as pop() extract firstly subtrahend and then minuend 
            result.append( - result.pop() + result.pop())
        elif x == "multiply":
            result.append( result.pop() * result.pop() )
        elif x == "divide":
             y = ((result.pop()))
             z = (result.pop())
             # (2) add 1.* to convert result to float  
             result.append( 1.* z/y )
        else:
              result.append(x)
    return (result[-1])
```